# Google Login consent page does not ask for permission for all scopes my application requests

Tags: google-api, photo

I have created a small java app that downloads and handles all photos uploaded by my familys devices to Google Drive.

But now Google Drives is no longer used for storing photos, so I need access to Google Photos instead.

But no matter what I do, I cannot get access via the java API.

And now I figured out the problem. Even though I have updated my applications scope requirements in the google dev. console ([pic 1](http://www.fafdifh.dk/scopes.png)), google does NOT ask for permission for the Photo Library scopes at login ([pic 2](http://www.fafdifh.dk/consent.png)).

And thus I am not allowed access the the Photo Library, but get:

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:55) ~[gax-1.45.0.jar:1.45.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72) ~[gax-grpc-1.45.0.jar:1.45.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60) ~[gax-grpc-1.45.0.jar:1.45.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97) ~[gax-grpc-1.45.0.jar:1.45.0]
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68) ~[api-common-1.8.1.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1015) ~[guava-28.0-jre.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30) ~[guava-28.0-jre.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1137) ~[guava-28.0-jre.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:957) ~[guava-28.0-jre.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:748) ~[guava-28.0-jre.jar:?]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:492) ~[grpc-stub-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:467) ~[grpc-stub-1.10.1.jar:1.10.1]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[grpc-api-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-api-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-api-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:700) ~[grpc-core-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[grpc-api-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-api-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-api-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:399) ~[grpc-core-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:500) ~[grpc-core-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:65) ~[grpc-core-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:592) ~[grpc-core-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:508) ~[grpc-core-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:632) ~[grpc-core-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) ~[grpc-core-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
    Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57) ~[gax-1.45.0.jar:1.45.0]
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112) ~[gax-1.45.0.jar:1.45.0]
        at com.google.photos.library.v1.internal.InternalPhotosLibraryClient.listAlbums(InternalPhotosLibraryClient.java:913) ~[google-photos-library-client-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at com.google.photos.library.v1.internal.InternalPhotosLibraryClient.listAlbums(InternalPhotosLibraryClient.java:891) ~[google-photos-library-client-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at com.google.photos.library.v1.PhotosLibraryClient.listAlbums(PhotosLibraryClient.java:201) ~[google-photos-library-client-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at dk.fafdifh.photo.manager.cron.PhotoSynchronizer.fetch(PhotoSynchronizer.java:208) ~[classes/:?]
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) [?:1.8.0_212]
        at dk.fafdifh.photo.manager.cron.PhotoSynchronizer.fetch(PhotoSynchronizer.java:132) [classes/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) [spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533) ~[grpc-api-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
    ... 23 more
```

Oh, and by the way - yes; I have tried deleting all credentials from the application, revoking the application's access to my account and start from scratch. To no avail.

I have not tried creating an entirely new application in google dev console, but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

What scopes are included in the consent page is NOT decided by what scopes are added to the application in the dev. console auth page.

It is (of course, stupido!) decided by what scopes are listed in the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow scopes list.

So simple...

Comment: Oh, and by the way, the Google Photos api **SUCKS** big time. You cannot even download photos via the api directly; and if you do indirectly (via the baseUrl of the photo), some META data - like Location (!) - is removed, and you get a downscaled version of the photo.